# Automatically shut off Splunk HEC when volume gets too high

Tags: splunk

We have an issue where certain HEC feeds will burst in volume and blow out our daily ingest license. Is there an automated way to shut off the offending HEC when volume reaches a high level?

Comment: Just a thought - are you able to control the max_number_of_acked_requests_pending_query or 
max_number_of_acked_requests_pending_query_per_ack_channel  in limits.conf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is not uncommon, but the answer still is "no".  Splunk does not provide a way to cut off ingestion when a volume limit is reached.